# php doc_root in php.ini and DocumentRoot in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache

I wanted to learn more about PHP and Apache so I decided to install them manually. I don't exactly understand how the two files work together (or if they even go hand in hand in this situation). Whenever I load the localhost webpage, the location of the php files are directed from what I specify in the httpd.conf file. I've made two root folders just for the sake of testing, C:/Users/Alex/test and C:\Users\Alex\My Websites. Apache does not actually use the location that I specified in php.ini (doc_root = "C:\Users\Alex\My Websites"), but instead uses the location that I specified in httpd.conf (DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Alex/test" ). Can anyone please explain when is the root useful in php.ini?

Comment: Hint #1: it's php runned by apache, not the other way around.

Comment: I see, so what is the root that I specified in php.ini used for?

Comment: Why to ask if there is a documentation available: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.doc-root ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're running `mod_php` inside of Apache (this is the most common way to run PHP under Apache). That means that the PHP environment is controlled entirely by Apache (in Unix environments Apache has its own user as well). You can reconfigure it to use `Fast CGI` (which is the only way to run PHP under other web servers like nginx) and the setting will matter under that type of setup.

Here's the [manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.doc-root) for the setting

> PHP's "root directory" on the server. Only used if non-empty. If PHP
>   is configured with safe mode, no files outside this directory are
>   served. If PHP was not compiled with FORCE_REDIRECT, you should set
>   doc_root if you are running PHP as a CGI under any web server (other
>   than IIS). The alternative is to use the cgi.force_redirect
>   configuration below.

Comment: The only safe_mode I see is this: [SQL]; http://php.net/sql.safe-mode
sql.safe_mode = Off...Is this the one?

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.4 or later (and it sounds like you are) then you won't have that option at all, as it [was removed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php).